# Custom authorization with Azure AD authentication

Tags: asp.net, authorization, azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-2.0

I am developing a service fabric stateless web application using ASP.NET Core 2.0. This application is using Azure AD to authenticate users from multiple AD tenants. What I want to achieve is using my own role based authorization which can be configured in my application using the authorized user. These roles are stored in my application.

In my current implementation I add authorization to my application by adding a policy with my custom `IAuthorizationRequirement`. During the authorization of the requirement claims are added based on the users permissions. This means that claims are added post-login. The `[Authorize(Roles = "role")]` attribute also doesn't work because the role claims are added post-login

What is the correct way to implement this custom authorization which uses the authenticated user from Azure AD?

Comment: Why don't you add them during login?

Comment: @juunas That is the goal. But I am not sure how to implement that because Azure AD is used for authentication.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll write an answer showing how to do that pretty soon :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your own custom claims after the user signs in through the `OnTokenValidated` event:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
{
    Configuration.GetSection("OpenIdConnect").Bind(o);
    o.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
        {
            string oid = ctx.Principal.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier");

            var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<AuthorizationDbContext>();

            var objectIdGuid = Guid.Parse(oid);
            bool isSuperAdmin = await db.SuperAdmins.AnyAsync(a => a.ObjectId == objectIdGuid);
            if (isSuperAdmin)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>();
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Roles.SuperAdmin));
                var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MyTestAppIdentity");

                ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Here as an example we check from a database whether the user is a super admin. Then if they are, we create a new identity for them with the necessary role as a claim.

All the identities are combined on the principal to produce their claim set, so all the other claims will still be available too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to implement it, but I currently also use the `.AddAzureAd` method to implement my Azure AD authentication. Because this method also uses OpenIdConnect an exception occurs: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: OpenIdConnect'`. This exception occurs when using both `.AddAzureAd` and `.AddOpenIdConnect`. Do you know any solution for this problem?

Comment: You need to implement the event handling code inside the AddAzureAd handler. You can't add another OIDC handler.

Comment: The AzureAdOptions are different from the OpenIdConnectOptions. They do not have an Events property. The AddAzureAd method uses the OIDC options internally, but these are defined in a private class. How would you implement the event handling code in the AddAzureAd method?

Comment: Umm, in the template it generates you the AddAzureAd extension method. You just need to modify that. In Extensions/AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs, where it says `builder.AddOpenIdConnect();`, change it to what I posted, though you do not need `Configuration.GetSection().Bind()`, since it does that already in a different way.

Comment: And obviously you need to modify the DB access code and business logic for applying roles to your specific case :)